# Loop over Ansible variable array in Jinja2 template to create nested dictionary

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

Here is the output.

```
"result.containers":[
   {
      "Image":"ca.docker/webproxy:1.0.0",
      "Names":[
         "/customer1"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Image":"docker.local/egacustomer:1.0.1",
      "Names":[
         "/webproxy"
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm trying to create a nested dictionary using jinja2.
i'm trying to achieve the below using results.container and setfact.

```
"containerlist": "[webproxy:
                     name: customer1,
                   egacustomer:
                     name: webproxy]"
```

Here is my jinja2 code.

```
- set_fact:
      containerlist: |
           [
           {% for item in result.containers %}
           {{ item.Image | regex_replace('.*?/(.*?):.*', '\\1') }}:
                     'name': {{ item.Names | regex_replace("^/", "") }},
           {% endfor %}
```

Which throws the error. Could someone help me with the right Jinja2 Code.Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
"containerlist": "[\n\\1:\n          'name': ['/customer'],\n\\1:\n          'name': ['/webproxy'],\n,\n]\n"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you're trying to do I would normalize use an Ansible looping task rather than trying to use a Jinja `{% for ... %}` loop.  For example, these tasks...

```
    - set_fact:
        container_list: >-
          {{
          container_list + [{
            item.Image.split('/')[-1].split(':')[0]:
              item.Names[0][1:]
          }]
          }}
      loop: "{{ result.containers }}"
      vars:
        container_list: []

    - debug:
        var: container_list
```

In the `set_fact` task, we're looping over `result.containers`, and for each iteration of the loop we redefine `container_list` as "the current contents of `container_list` + a new dictionary".

The above produces the following output:

```
TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Image': 'ca.docker/webproxy:1.0.0', 'Names': ['/customer1']})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Image': 'docker.local/egacustomer:1.0.1', 'Names': ['/webproxy']})

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "container_list": [
        {
            "webproxy": "customer1"
        },
        {
            "egacustomer": "webproxy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me change it to a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: If you update your question to show the desired format, I can give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks,larsks. I could populate dictionary with the code.


`set_fact:
          containeruplist: "{{ containeruplist|default({}) | combine( {item.Image.split('/')[-1].split(':')[0]:item.Names[0][1:]} ) }}"
        loop: "{{ resultup | json_query('containers[*]') }}"`